# Error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imported' in 'where clause' when installing Magento 2.3.6

Tags: installation, magento2

I am installing Magento 2.3.6 by the guide in https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/prereq/nginx.html. I installed MySql 5.7 for Ubuntu 20.04 by following https://techexpert.tips/mysql/installing-mysql-5-7-ubuntu-20-04/. When i run

```
--base-url=http://localhost/magento2ee \
--db-host=localhost \
--db-name=magento \
--db-user=magento \
--db-password=magento \
--backend-frontname=admin \
--admin-firstname=admin \
--admin-lastname=admin \
--admin-email=admin@admin.com \
--admin-user=admin \
--admin-password=admin123 \
--language=en_US \
--currency=USD \
--timezone=America/Chicago \
--use-rewrites=1
```

It displayed like that:

```
[Progress: 734 / 1001]
Module 'Amazon_Core':
[Progress: 735 / 1001]
Module 'Amazon_Login':
[Progress: 736 / 1001]
Module 'Amazon_Payment':
[Progress: 737 / 1001]
Module 'Dotdigitalgroup_Email':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 
In Mysql.php line 110:
                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imported'   
  in 'where clause', query was: UPDATE `email_catalog` SET `processe  
  d` = ? WHERE (imported) AND (modified IS NULL OR modified = 0) 

In Mysql.php line 91:
                                                                      
  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'imported'   
  in 'where clause'
```

I searched for it but haven't found the answer. Waiting for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I completely uninstall and reinstall Mysql then the installation runs smoothly. Thank you.